# Facebook ios dialog suddenly stopped working

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I am working with Facebook SDK to share a message on the user's wall.
It was working fine until yesterday, but now it's broken.
I started getting message:

```
An error occured please try again later.
```

Did anything change on the Facebook side that prevents dialog to be present?

```
dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
              @"Lost Pet", @"name",
              @"Help!", @"caption",
              url, @"link",
              [petInfo objectForKey:@"picture"], @"picture",
               description, @"description",nil];


[facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:dictionary andDelegate:self];
```

Any ideas how to approach it? 
I tried to include app_id in the params.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your example is prefilling captions for posted images, which is a Facebook policy no-no - you might want to check your app for any developer alerts concerning this, which could be causing the error. You're also using the older "feed dialog" to post. The iOS 3.5 SDK included Native Share dialogs, which are much faster. Check the below resources for how to implement these:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/share-native-dialogs-ios-sdk/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorial/iossdk/upgrading-from-3.2-to-3.5/